# How do you convert '\0' to const void*?

Tags: c, posix

I'm migrating some code to u18, and it seems the poisix write function changed signatures

`ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t nbytes);`

The call used to be  `write(output, '\0', 1);`

However I would get the exception `error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const void*'` on u18.

What is the right way to initialize a null character array?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't previously write `"\0"` and not `'\0'`? The former is a string, i.e. (pointer to) char array, consisting of one char with value 0 while the latter is just one char with value 0 (not an array).

Comment: `"\0"` is a character array of 2 characters, both being `'\0'`. If that is what you want, you're fine.

Comment: @thebusybee -- Technically `"\0"` is simply a literal *empty-string* of 1-character. (e.g. a string consisting only of the *nul-terminating* character ASCII 0)

Comment: I would use `""` instead of `"\0"`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Can you back up your claim by a citation from the standard? AFAIK each string literal has a `'\0'` appended, independent of the characters between the quotation marks.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's interesting. Compilers am teh smrt, but I figured it would still give you  literal with 2 nuls, the one the programmer asked for and the one the compiler always throws on the end of the literal. I can totally see the As-If rule kicking in here, just wouldn't expect it.

Comment: @thebusybee - now you have me thinking. I cannot give you a cite. But, through experimentation initializing arrays with `"\0"` and `""`, both initialize to the empty-string, but you are correct in the case of `"\0"` `sizeof` shows 2 whereas with `""`, `sizeof` shows `1` -- so there is a semantic difference -- which I now must find.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin C17 standard, chapter 6.4.5, paragraph 6, first sentence: "In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals."

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is were I was at [C11 Standard - 6.4.5 String literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5) Good evening -- learned something that was apparent but not attached to a standard paragraph -- it is now.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Re: ""\0" is simply a literal empty-string of 1-character. " --> Try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof ("\0"));`.  I get 2.  Yes `"\0"` is a _string_ of 1-character, followed by another _null character_: a 2-byte _string literal_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to initialize a C string character array would be `""`, which is an empty string literal containing nothing but a null terminator. The difference between `""` and `'\0'` is that the former has a memory location - it is an array that decays into a pointer and so you can assign a pointer to it directly. While `'\0'` is just a character constant with no memory location.

However in case of Linux `write`, you don't need to provide a null terminated string. It works by checking the size parameter and does not look for null termination like a string handling function.

But if you want to write one single character - the null terminator - to a file, then the correct way would be:

```
write(output, "", 1);
```